# Moving azure blobs to another region

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a storage account with over 600k blobs.
I want to move them to another storage account, in a different region.
After googling I found someone recommending "Azure storage explorer". When I tried it, it was extremely slow. It looked like it was going to take about a week to transfer them all, but then after 24 hours, it has cancelled the copy and I can see no option to restart it. 
Is there a fast and convenient way of moving a large number of blobs from one storage account, in one region, to another storage account, in another region?

Comment: I am now trying azcopy, which seems to be much faster

Comment: Yeah az copy is the way to go for this kind of migration process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the command,

```
azcopy
```

Example,

```
azcopy cp "https://<source-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<blob-path>?<SAS-token>" "https://<destination-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<blob-path>"
```

Read more **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/copy?view=azure-cli-latest)**